# Why do the horizontal components cancel? I don't understand what is the horizontal component here

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> [image]

**My Attempt:**

$\vec{E}=\frac{\lambda}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\int_{0}^{2\pi r}(\cos(\frac{x}{r})i+\sin(\frac{x}{r})j+zk) dx=\frac{\lambda 2 \pi r z }{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}(r^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}k$

**Solution given in solution Manual:**
[image]

**My Question:-**
Both the answer matches. But my method is too lengthy. I am new to physics. Can you please help me? Why do the horizontal components cancel?

Comment: @Hilmar points out that the book uses a symmetry argument.  That's exactly right.  Symmetry arguments are *very powerful* as you have discovered.  They are used frequently in physics, especial in E&M.  Get used to them, and be prepared to  look for where they can be used, and use them whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

Symmetry. Each piece of loop can be paired with an opposite piece of loop that will create a field with the opposite radial direction and the same magnitude.

Comment: Sorry! Yesterday, I couldn't see the answer. I apologize for that. How do I prove by the equation? I don't understand the symmetric argument. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line that denotes the radius of that circle. If you were to continue that line to the other side of the circle, the diameter line would then connect two points on the circle. These points, within the context of your question, can be thought of "counterpoints" to each other, and, with these points being exactly opposite one another on the circle, the horizontal components of the electric field produced by those points cancel each other out, and the resultant value is zero (equal in electric magnitude, and oppositely apposed to one another).

Now, rotate that diameter line around the circle and the same thing can be applied to all point-pairs on the circle.

Simply put, symmetry allows the automatic assumption that the horizontal component cancels.